# Is it possible for a Messenger Platform bot to initiate group chat with two or more humans?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Is it possible to create a bot that can connect two people (assume they're already registered with the bot) together by starting a group chat with the two of them?

If not, I'm open to alternate solutions to allow a bot to connect a human user with another human user, if anyone knows one.

Comment: Messenger Bots are for communication between one user and a page. Don’t try to misuse them for anything else, you won’t get that through review anyway. If users want to group chat with each other, the can do so via the already existing Facebook UI.

Answer (score 1):

Group chat is not supported. As an alternative you can build a chat extension which allows you to make some of your functionality available in group chat, including allowing multiple people to utilize shared resources. For examples, look at chat extensions that are already in the discover tab.